# Derived class object override a function of base class in a vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, vector, polymorphism

so I'm having an issue of calling the override function of a derived class when it's stored in an array of it's base class.

The base class is called Obstacle, and the derived class is Cliff. Obstacle has a virtual function called drawToBackground, and Cliff, which inherits from Obstacle also has a function called drawToBackground, both of which are void.

I then have a vector of Obstacles, called obstsVec. In this vector, I store a bunch of Obstacles and a Cliff. Now say that the cliff is the fifth element of the vector. When I call obstsVec[5].drawToBackground(); it calls the drawToBackground function from the Obstacle class, not the cliff class.

Is this a feature in c++ or might I just have something declared wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to be sure without code, but I think you need to look into *object slicing*.

Comment: How do you store a `Cliff` in a `vector<Obstacle>`?

Comment: @Beta not sure. I'm coming from c# to c++, and I'm pretty sure this was possible in c#. Guess I was wrong to use it in c++ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing only the base class in your vector, as @juanchopanza has already mentioned, you have done what is called *object slicing*. What you need to do is store the objects polymorphically, via a pointer.

```
std::vector<Obstacle*> myObstacles;
myObstacles.push_back(new Cliff());
myObstacles[0]->drawToBackground();
// Remember to delete when you're done
```

Of course if you've got access to C++11, then you can forget about the memory management side of things:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obstacle>> myObstacles;
myObstacles.push_back(new Cliff());
for (const auto &obstacle : myObstacles)
{
    obstacle->drawToBackground();
}
// No need to delete anything
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not very familiar with much of the advanced stuff, so neither of those solutions make much sense to me. What does myObstacles[0]->drawToBackground(); do? Nothing in the second example makes sense to me, so I'll probably avoid using that method unless someone can explain it line by line to me.

Comment: Just the very basics. I know that they point to a place in memory, and you can access that place using the & operator or something. Pointers are probably an area I should get more familiar with. (I'm coming from c# to c++ so pointers are entirely new to me)

Comment: @RyanMartin my examples store the objects as pointers, which you need to do, else you can't refer to them polymorphically (i.e. call virtual methods on the instances).

Comment: Okay so I think I would like to use the second method, since I'm using c++ 11. But I don't understand what's going on in the for loop. Would you mind explaining what's going on here?

Comment: It's called the "range-based for loop" which is a new feature in C++11. It loops over all the contents of `myObstacles` and then calls the `drawToBackground` method on each.

Comment: Ah of that makes sense. Thanks for the info, looks like I should get it working. I'll try it out later today and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your classes could look something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Obstacles {
public:
    Obstacles() {};
    virtual void drawToBackground() {
    std::cout << "Obstacle ";
    }
};

class Cliff : public Obstacles {
public:
    Cliff() : Obstacles() {};
    virtual void drawToBackground() {
    std::cout << "Cliff ";
    }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<Obstacles*> vec;
    vec.push_back(new Obstacles());
    vec.push_back(new Cliff());
    vec[1]->drawToBackground();
    delete vec[1];
    delete vec[0];
    vec.clear();
}
```

You mentioned arrays above...make sure never to use arrays polymorphically, as this will lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: "using arrays polymorphically" is not undefined behavior. Object slicing would take place here. So no polymorphism would be achieved.